# Phonegap app post to sql not being sent - deviceready?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

I'm writing a simple Phonegap app to gather some data and send it to sql. Works fine from a browser but when built as a phonegap app, the data is not sent, although everything else works a charm including the checking, alerts and redirect to index.html. The problem may only be that I need to add the deviceready function in, and I've tried to add it but when I wrap it round the code it just skips to the window.location event and no data is posted.

I've tried:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkSubmit, false);
function Checksubmit() {
  ... 
}
```

and also

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", 
  function checkSubmit() {
    ....
  }, false);
```

but these don't seem to execute properly.

Any help greatly appreciated!

This is a cutdown version of the app code.

```
<script>

function checkSubmit() {

var todayNum = Number(new Date());
var storedDate = localStorage.getItem("storedDate");
var diff = todayNum - storedDate;
var subDelay = 60000;

if (!storedDate || storedDate === null || diff > subDelay) {
  localStorage.setItem("storedDate", todayNum);
  $(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var postData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            url: 'http://mydblocation.com/sqlin.php',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log(data);
                alert('There was an error adding your submission, please try again later.');
            }
        });
        alert("Thanks for your submission!");
        window.location = "index.html";
        return false;
    });
    });
} 
if (todayNum - storedDate < subDelay) {
  alert("You've already submitted! You will be able to submit again in 1 minute.");
  window.location = "index.html";
}
}

</script>

<body onload="checkSubmit()">

<div class="container">
        <form id="form">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
        <p style="  font-family:verdana; text-align:justify">
        Name
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <p style="  font-family:verdana; text-align:justify">
        Location:
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="location"></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="location">
                <option>Birmingham</option>
                <option>Manchester</option>
                <option>London</option>
                <option>New York</option>
                <option>Brussels</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">send</button>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you installe the plugin  device in your project ? cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device

Comment: I've added the plugin via config.xml as per Phonegap documentation, rather than direct from cordova. Unfortunately this hasn't resolved. Additionally I have had this posting without any checking for submission or onready before so not so sure this is the problem.